# DS3231 RTC I2C (ESP-IDF only / No Wire.h)

Tags: c, esp32, i2c, esp-idf

When using the Arduino Framework with RTClib, the connection to the DS3231 RTC works fine, so I know everything is wired up correctly. However, my project must stick to using the ESP-IDF framework only, so I have to adapt to their I2C library

Here's my minimal code:

```
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "driver/i2c.h"

#define I2C_PORT I2C_NUM_0
#define I2C_SLAVE_ADDR 0x68
#define SDA_PIN 3
#define SCL_PIN 4

void initRTCI2C() {
    int i2c_master_port = I2C_PORT;
    i2c_config_t conf = {
        .mode = I2C_MODE_MASTER,
        .sda_io_num = SDA_PIN,
        .sda_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE,
        .scl_io_num = SCL_PIN,
        .scl_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE,
        .master.clk_speed = 100000,
        .clk_flags = I2C_SCLK_SRC_FLAG_FOR_NOMAL
    };
    i2c_param_config(i2c_master_port, &conf);
    i2c_driver_install(i2c_master_port, conf.mode, 0, 0, 0);
}

void readTime() {

    i2c_port_t i2c_num = I2C_PORT;

    uint8_t size = 7;
    uint8_t data_read[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    uint8_t start_address[] = {0};

    esp_err_t err = i2c_master_write_read_device(i2c_num, I2C_SLAVE_ADDR, start_address, 1, data_read, size, pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
    if (err != ESP_OK) fprintf(stdout, "Err:%i\n", err);

    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%x ", data_read[i]);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
}

void app_main() {
    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(5000));
    fprintf(stdout, "Start\n");
    initRTCI2C();
    
    while(1) {
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(2000));
        readTime();
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
Start
Err:-1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Err:-1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Err:-1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This might be useful. The yellow is the SDA signal from the same read clock process using RTClib. The pink is from the code provided. Looks like there's a configuration setting that needs to be made to get the correct level:

[image]

Update: changing the pins worked for me, though I don't know why. I stripped down the code from this example code: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/peripherals/i2c/i2c_self_test/main/i2c_example_main.c

It should be noted that I'm on an ESP32-S3 chip from Adafruit

Bizarrely, it works when the Slave mode is initialized on pin 7 before initializing the Master mode

```
/* i2c - Example

   For other examples please check:
   https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples

   See README.md file to get detailed usage of this example.

   This example code is in the Public Domain (or CC0 licensed, at your option.)

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, this
   software is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR
   CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "driver/i2c.h"
#include "sdkconfig.h"

static const char *TAG = "i2c-example";

#define _I2C_NUMBER(num) I2C_NUM_##num
#define I2C_NUMBER(num) _I2C_NUMBER(num)

#define ANY_NUMBER 0

#define CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE_PORT_NUM 0
#define CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE_SCL ANY_NUMBER
#define CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE_SDA 7
#define CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE_ADDRESS ANY_NUMBER

#define CONFIG_I2C_MASTER_PORT_NUM 1
#define CONFIG_I2C_MASTER_SCL 4
#define CONFIG_I2C_MASTER_SDA 3
#define CONFIG_I2C_MASTER_FREQUENCY 100000

#define portTICK_RATE_MS 40



#define DATA_LENGTH 512                  /*!< Data buffer length of test buffer */

#define I2C_SLAVE_SCL_IO CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE_SCL               /*!< gpio number for i2c slave clock */
#define I2C_SLAVE_SDA_IO CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE_SDA               /*!< gpio number for i2c slave data */
#define I2C_SLAVE_NUM I2C_NUMBER(CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE_PORT_NUM) /*!< I2C port number for slave dev */
#define I2C_SLAVE_TX_BUF_LEN (2 * DATA_LENGTH)              /*!< I2C slave tx buffer size */
#define I2C_SLAVE_RX_BUF_LEN (2 * DATA_LENGTH)              /*!< I2C slave rx buffer size */

#define I2C_MASTER_SCL_IO CONFIG_I2C_MASTER_SCL               /*!< gpio number for I2C master clock */
#define I2C_MASTER_SDA_IO CONFIG_I2C_MASTER_SDA               /*!< gpio number for I2C master data  */
#define I2C_MASTER_NUM I2C_NUMBER(CONFIG_I2C_MASTER_PORT_NUM) /*!< I2C port number for master dev */
#define I2C_MASTER_FREQ_HZ CONFIG_I2C_MASTER_FREQUENCY        /*!< I2C master clock frequency */
#define I2C_MASTER_TX_BUF_DISABLE 0                           /*!< I2C master doesn't need buffer */
#define I2C_MASTER_RX_BUF_DISABLE 0                           /*!< I2C master doesn't need buffer */

#define BH1750_SENSOR_ADDR 0x68   /*!< slave address for BH1750 sensor */
#define BH1750_CMD_START 0   /*!< Operation mode */
#define ESP_SLAVE_ADDR CONFIG_I2C_SLAVE_ADDRESS /*!< ESP32 slave address, you can set any 7bit value */
#define WRITE_BIT I2C_MASTER_WRITE              /*!< I2C master write */
#define READ_BIT I2C_MASTER_READ                /*!< I2C master read */
#define ACK_CHECK_EN 0x1                        /*!< I2C master will check ack from slave*/
#define ACK_CHECK_DIS 0x0                       /*!< I2C master will not check ack from slave */
#define ACK_VAL 0x0                             /*!< I2C ack value */
#define NACK_VAL 0x1                            /*!< I2C nack value */


/**
 * @brief test code to operate on BH1750 sensor
 *
 * 1. set operation mode(e.g One time L-resolution mode)
 * _________________________________________________________________
 * | start | slave_addr + wr_bit + ack | write 1 byte + ack  | stop |
 * --------|---------------------------|---------------------|------|
 * 2. wait more than 24 ms
 * 3. read data
 * ______________________________________________________________________________________
 * | start | slave_addr + rd_bit + ack | read 1 byte + ack  | read 1 byte + nack | stop |
 * --------|---------------------------|--------------------|--------------------|------|
 */
static esp_err_t i2c_master_sensor_test(i2c_port_t i2c_num, uint8_t *data_h, uint8_t *data_l)
{
    int ret;
    i2c_cmd_handle_t cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create();
    i2c_master_start(cmd);
    i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, BH1750_SENSOR_ADDR << 1 | WRITE_BIT, ACK_CHECK_EN);
    i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, BH1750_CMD_START, ACK_CHECK_EN);
    i2c_master_stop(cmd);
    ret = i2c_master_cmd_begin(i2c_num, cmd, 1000 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
    i2c_cmd_link_delete(cmd);
    if (ret != ESP_OK) {
        return ret;
    }
    vTaskDelay(30 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
    cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create();
    i2c_master_start(cmd);
    i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, BH1750_SENSOR_ADDR << 1 | READ_BIT, ACK_CHECK_EN);
    i2c_master_read_byte(cmd, data_h, ACK_VAL);
    i2c_master_read_byte(cmd, data_l, NACK_VAL);
    i2c_master_stop(cmd);
    ret = i2c_master_cmd_begin(i2c_num, cmd, 1000 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
    i2c_cmd_link_delete(cmd);
    return ret;
}

/**
 * @brief i2c master initialization
 */
static esp_err_t i2c_master_init(void)
{
    int i2c_master_port = I2C_MASTER_NUM;
    i2c_config_t conf = {
        .mode = I2C_MODE_MASTER,
        .sda_io_num = I2C_MASTER_SDA_IO,
        .sda_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_DISABLE,
        .scl_io_num = I2C_MASTER_SCL_IO,
        .scl_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE,
        .master.clk_speed = I2C_MASTER_FREQ_HZ,
        // .clk_flags = I2C_SCLK_SRC_FLAG_FOR_NOMAL,          /*!< Optional, you can use I2C_SCLK_SRC_FLAG_* flags to choose i2c source clock here. */
    };
    esp_err_t err = i2c_param_config(i2c_master_port, &conf);
    if (err != ESP_OK) {
        return err;
    }
    return i2c_driver_install(i2c_master_port, conf.mode, I2C_MASTER_RX_BUF_DISABLE, I2C_MASTER_TX_BUF_DISABLE, 0);
}

/**
 * @brief i2c slave initialization
 */
static esp_err_t i2c_slave_init(void)
{
    int i2c_slave_port = I2C_SLAVE_NUM;
    i2c_config_t conf_slave = {
        .sda_io_num = I2C_SLAVE_SDA_IO,
        .sda_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE,
        .scl_io_num = I2C_SLAVE_SCL_IO,
        .scl_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE,
        .mode = I2C_MODE_SLAVE,
        .slave.addr_10bit_en = 0,
        .slave.slave_addr = ESP_SLAVE_ADDR,
    };
    esp_err_t err = i2c_param_config(i2c_slave_port, &conf_slave);
    if (err != ESP_OK) {
        return err;
    }
    return i2c_driver_install(i2c_slave_port, conf_slave.mode, I2C_SLAVE_RX_BUF_LEN, I2C_SLAVE_TX_BUF_LEN, 0);
}

static void i2c_test_task(void *arg)
{
    int ret;
    uint32_t task_idx = (uint32_t)arg;
    uint8_t sensor_data_h, sensor_data_l;
    int cnt = 0;
    while (1) {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Level: %i", gpio_get_level(GPIO_NUM_3));
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "TASK[%lu] test cnt: %d", task_idx, cnt++);
        ret = i2c_master_sensor_test(I2C_MASTER_NUM, &sensor_data_h, &sensor_data_l);
        if (ret == ESP_ERR_TIMEOUT) {
            printf("I2C Timeout\n");
        } else if (ret == ESP_OK) {
            printf("*******************\n");
            printf("TASK[%lu]  MASTER READ SENSOR( BH1750 )\n", task_idx);
            printf("*******************\n");
            printf("data_h: %02x\n", sensor_data_h);
            printf("data_l: %02x\n", sensor_data_l);
            printf("sensor val: %.02f [Lux]\n", (sensor_data_h << 8 | sensor_data_l) / 1.2);
        } else {
            printf("%s: No ack, sensor not connected...skip...\n", esp_err_to_name(ret));
        }
        
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
        //---------------------------------------------------
    }
}

void app_main(void)
{
    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(4000));
    // ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2c_slave_init()); //Comment this out to make it stop working
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2c_master_init());
    i2c_test_task(0);
}
```

Comment: This may help [if you've not seen it already]: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/i2c.html

Comment: Sorry to say, I have poured through that page and the esp32 arduino framework source code. But of course that doesn't mean I didn't miss something. Just have to keep working at it

Comment: Why pin 4 and 5? it looks a lot of like inherited from Arduino Uno A4 and A5 instead of based on ESP32 i2c pins. Do you config your project using esp-idf-config?

Comment: I'm using pins 3 and 4 per the default pins on this board: https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/110811

Comment: Nope, turns out the code does work on pins 6 and 9. Doesn't really answer the question, but at least I have something to work with